# Display the distance between a user's current location and an annotation in a Label

Tags: objective-c, android-mapview, tableview, cllocation

I want to display the distance between a user's current location and another annotation (displayed on my MapView) in a label on my custom table cell.

Each cell displays the name of a cafe (nameLabel), and underneath, I want it to display their distance away from each cafe (distanceLabel).

My **MapViewController.m** uses this code to calculate the distance between a user's current location and the closest cafes:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    for (MapViewAnnotation *annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [annotation coordinate];
        CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coord.latitude longitude:coord.longitude];
        annotation.distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
        CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
        annotation.distance = calculatedDistance;
    }
```

I've already set up my custom cell, I just want to know what I should put into my TableView code (TableViewController.m) in order to display the Calculated Distance inside of my text label (called **distanceLabel**).

**E.g. how do I finish this line?**

```
cell.distanceLabel.text =
```

**UPDATE**

Just tried adding the reference to my TableViewController.h, but xcode keeps throwing me the error "Redefinition of 'CLLocationDistance' as different kind of symbol".

```
@class CLLocationDistance; 

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationDistance *calculatedDistance;
```

**UPDATE**

**.h file**

[image]

****UPDATE**

**.m file****

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a forward reference for CLLocationDistance calculatedDistance in fx. Your .h . CLLocationDistance is typedef as a double, a prmitive data type, so don't use a pointer in your forward reference (CLLocationDistance calulatedDistance; or @property  CLLocationDistance calulatedDistance;). Then do the following:

```
 cell.distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", calculatedDistance];
```

So infact you dont have to create another/new double and assign it to calculatedDistance. Sorry for any confusion..:)

Comment: See my "Update" above. Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: You dont have to make a forward reference for the class of CLLocationDistance, only as the ivar property. First you define CLLocationDistance as a class and then as a property, thus the error, your a redefining it. Only make a property. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Ok, so did exactly that! But now it's giving me this error: "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'double *' for this line: cell.distanceLabel.text = calculatedDistance;

Comment: Oh, my fault: Updated my answer above. :)

Comment: I've put double distance = calculatedDistance; into my .m controller, and it says "Use of undeclared identifier calculatedDistance" even though it is declared in my .h file (@property CLLocationDistance *calculatedDistance), and synthesized in the .m file... Am I going crazy/writing it wrong? Ha ha ha

Comment: Hi! Lol updated my question and uploaded pictures. Still throws me the  error. Maybe I put something in the wrong place? Take a look.

Comment: As I say above (in my answer), you infact don't have to create a new double and assign to calculatedDistance. So delete that double and do as I have described in the answer above. I am sorry if I have confused you more than clarifying.

Comment: Ahhhh okay. Just deleted the double. I run the simulator, and there don't appear to be any errors, but it throws me a SIGABRT and stops the app: "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCES is caused when sending a message to an object that is no longer in memory. You need to retain the calculatedDistance by putting "self" in front of calculatedDistance in the "didUpdateToLocation" function, like so: self.calculatedDistance. Try that! Please let me know if it is not working :)btw does the Bad acces end at a breakpoint? If yes, where?

Comment: Tried adding self to the didUpdateToLocation function, e.g. annotation.distance = self.calculatedDistance; and it gives me a failed error :( Error doesn't show up at a breakpoint.